# List of topics in mathmatics

Tags: soft-question, learning

Is there any list out there which lists all of the areas/branches/subjects/topics (including current research fields) in mathematics? (not the MSC, which misses out on many topics, such as domain theory) I looked at wikipedia's page but they don't have everything structured until 1 list which is what I want.

Thanks

Comment: The MSC **does** include domain theory. "68Q55 View Publications (1980-now) Semantics [See also 03B70, 06B35, 18C50] ". For example, MR0405908 Scott, Dana, Data types as lattices. ... 68A05. "68A05 View Publications (1973-1984) Computers and computer systems" It is just not listed as "domain theory". There can be many synonyms. There are Primary and Secondary Classifications. It is not well defined. It varies over time as well.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you.

Comment: So does the MSC include _every_ single area & branch of math?

Comment: You should get the official story from [MSC2020](https://msc2020.org/) itself.

Comment: *So does the MSC include every single area & branch of math?* --- This got me wondering if I could come up with a seemingly existent mathematical notion that doesn't exist (at least not yet). Given that [bitopological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitopological_space) are not very well known, I decided to google a made-up obvious "next level" concept, "tritopological space". Not surprisingly, this notion actually exists! See [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tritopological+space%22) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tri+topological+space%22).

Comment: And apparently there is even the notion of a [quad-topological space](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quad-topological+space%22) $\dots$

Comment: And there is no list out there which includes that?

Comment: wikipedia has something on it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-topological_space

Comment: I actually have photocopies/printed-copies of several papers and a couple of Ph.D. dissertations, obtained over the past 30 some years, on bitopological spaces, so I'm somewhat familiar with them (and some of the motivation behind introducing the notion), but I thought I was being silly when (yesterday) I tried googling "tritopological space". And now we have [$n$-topological spaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n-topological+space%22), where presumably $n$ is a positive integer. **(continued)**

Comment: I suppose someone will eventually (if not already) consider the case where $n$ is a cardinal number, or an ordinal number, or an ordered set, or a net, $\ldots$ (none of which I suspect for $n \neq 2$ have much external motivation for the notion).

Comment: Ok thank you ..