# Where do we use the notions of generalized open sets in topology?

Tags: general-topology

Recently I have been asked to work on a generalized open set in fuzzy soft topological space as for my UG project. I have defined the same in fuzzy soft topological space and investigated some of its characteristics and also found that the generalized fuzzy soft open set I am working on forms a fuzzy soft topology. But I was wondering where this generalized fuzzy soft open set or the fuzzy soft topology it forms would be used. As we know similar generalizations of open sets also exist in general topological space such as regular open sets, pre-open sets, $\gamma$-open sets, semi-open sets, $\delta$-open sets, $\theta$-open sets etc. Some of which under given conditions could form a topology as well. So first I searched on the internet to see their applications in real life so that I can at least be sure that my work isn't merely a waste of time. But I haven't been able to find any definite evidence of their (or of the topological structure they form or of the properties which they exhibit) uses in real world. And here I am working on a generalized open set in fuzzy soft topological space and I can't even properly find the uses of the generalized open sets in general topology and that's why I am kind of confused and am just pondering whether my work would go in vain totally.

So my question is that are all these generalizations merely abstract concepts? Or, are they actually being used in certain fields off and on? Please give some insights and enlighten me.

Comment: These sound like questions you should ask whoever assigned you this work!

Comment: @Calvin Khor Agreed and I did ask sir but didn't get satisfactory answers (The answers that I have received nearly translates to "there should be some applications in certain fields and your job is only to investigate the properties of this particular generalized open set in fuzzy soft topological space.")  so only posted here. If this is not an appropriate site for posting such questions, then will you please suggest me one?

Comment: I would remind you that throughout math history many abstract objects without any obvious applications find applications in the future. Graph theory was a curiosity for over 100 years until it was used to categorize hydrocarbon structures and is now fundamental to the design of computer programs. Conic sections were purely mathematical curiosities for over 1000 years until Newton's gravitation laws showed they had application. In fact, the distinction between pure and applied mathematics is new, less than 200 years old. In the past no attempts were made to segregate them into different camps.

Comment: Generalized topological spaces and generalized open sets form a very niche area of topology that is rather removed from most mainstream mathematics ([my attempt at one way of making connections with other areas](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780); [a useful reference](https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-486)), but when you begin fuzzifying it, I think you've moved well into an inbred area that presently has almost no real contact with mainstream mathematical research (see my comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3666858/13130) for what in my opinion is another example).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Thank you sir for the links. I have just gone through the first link and have understood some of the things mentioned in your answer. I think I have seen such operators (actually their fuzzy soft versions to be precise) in one of the thesis papers which I am currently taking into account for preparing my own paper. But yes, if I continue to do research in this field in future as well then I'll surely consider these things more deeply.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you sir for your words. Your words have given me some hope!